# How to sum up values from an integer column of a pandas dataframe for each element of a list column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following example pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"list": [[a, b, c], [a, c, d], [c]],
                   "count": [3, 5, 1]})
```

I want as output a dictionary that contains as keys the elements of the list (a, b, c, d) and as values the sum of all `count` values for every occurrence of the element in the `lists` column. My example output would look like:

```
{"a": 8, "b": 3, "c": 9, "d": 5}
```

I tried zipping the `count` column to the `lists` column and then creating tuples for each element in the list and the count, but that does not work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) + [`pandas.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
res = df.explode("list").groupby("list")["count"].sum().to_dict()
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
{'a': 8, 'b': 3, 'c': 9, 'd': 5}
```